How do I increase the initial minor device number (64) for /dev/ttyS* devices on Linux?
Recently I needed to increase the maximum number of tty (not ttyS*) on the system from 63 to 128. But looking at the Linux source code I found that file include/uapi/linux/linux/vt.h contains
#define MIN_RN_CONSOLES 1 /* must be at least 1 */
#define MAX_RN_CONSOLES 63 /* serial lines start at 64 */

At the end it says serial lines start at 64
I checked it:
$ stat -c %Hr:%Lr /dev/tty63
4:63
$ stat -c %Hr:%Lr /dev/ttyS0
4:64

and indeed it starts from 64
I tried to find a similar line in the include files (like MIN_SERIAL_CONSOLES) but I couldn't find it.
How can I make the minor number of /dev/ttyS0 start with 129 so other 128 will belong to /dev/tty1...tty128?

The starting minor is hard-coded in most serial TTY drivers; for example in the 8250 driver:
struct uart_driver serial8250_reg = {
    .owner          = THIS_MODULE,
    .driver_name        = "serial",
    .dev_name       = "ttyS",
    .major          = TTY_MAJOR,
    .minor          = 64,
    .cons           = SERIAL8250_CONSOLE,
};

The .minor field is used to initialise the tty_driver’s .minor_start field:
    normal->minor_start = drv->minor;

Changing the “64” value should change the range used for serial drivers.
If you can’t use pseudoterminal interfaces you’ll have to modify all the relevant drivers for your target system.

So you only need to change .minor = 64 to something like .minor = 129 and the driver will start creating devices from 129?

Yes, it should.
